# Run AutoHotkey script when screen locked?

Tags: autohotkey

I've written a couple of scripts with AutoHotkey, but I notice they only work when a user is logged in and the screen isn't locked.

I'd like to schedule the script to run.  Does anyone know if that is possible with AutoHotkey, or if there is another program with similar functionality that can run a script when the screen is locked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the system task scheduler to schedule the execution of the script. The scheduler accepts a username and id and will run the script under that account.

Incidentally, I have found that hotkey mappings and hotstrings DO work when the screen is locked, but of course anything that sends keys to or otherwise interacts with open windows won't.